# Elasticity estimates for zero-truncated negative binomial part in the hurdle model

Tags: expected-value, regression-coefficients, zero-inflation, derivative, elasticity

I estimated a hurdle negative binomial regression model with zero-truncated negative binomial model as the count component in R using the pscl package. I wish to present elasticities for the count component and I am having a hard time figuring out the relation for the elasticity estimates from the regression coefficients because of the over-dispersion parameter involved. Can anyone assist me on this please?

E[y|y>0] = e^(βx+δ)/(1-(θ/(θ+e^(βx+δ)))^θ)

If I proceed I get to elasticity estimates, I am getting negative solutions which do not make sense. I read some papers which just present elasticities using the same approach as that for poisson or NB model for zero-truncated part but I am not sure if they are correct. Can anyone please point a way forward?